# Loading overlay on top of svg element

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I am stuck with a css/positioning problem. The goal is to have an overlay on top of a svg element as the image which is loaded there sometimes take a while until loaded completely.

The idea is to use the display property and bind it to the loading state of the component. Then if the image is loaded (onLoad event) the loading state is set to false. I am using react with material UI so the container elements will just result in a div element.

The problem now is that the overlay should have the exact size of the svg element. If I use the following css the overlay is way to large and creates an unnecessary scrollbar.

```
      <Container>
        <Container
          className="loading-background"
          style={{ display: loading ? "block" : "none" }}
        ></Container>
        <svg
          style={{ display: loading ? "none" : "block" }}
          viewBox={
            floor.imageData?.viewBox
              ? floor.imageData.viewBox.minx +
                ", " +
                floor.imageData.viewBox.miny +
                " ," +
                floor.imageData.viewBox.width +
                " ," +
                floor.imageData.viewBox.height
              : undefined
          }
        >
          <image
            width={
              floor.imageData?.viewBox
                ? floor.imageData?.viewBox.width
                : undefined
            }
            height={
              floor.imageData?.viewBox
                ? floor.imageData.viewBox.height
                : undefined
            }
            href={floor.imageData.imageURL}
            onLoad={imageLoaded}
          />
```

css:

```
.loading-background {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) url('loading-spinner.webp') no-repeat center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The overlay should scale with the svg element so it must have the exact same size also with different screen resolutions.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you forget `position:relative` on the parent?

Comment: Yes that was it. thanks.